# Why window.onpopstate is called twice using history.go?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've find this code that provides to disable browser back button using javascript. It works but when i press the back button it calls the console.log twice. Why?

```
history.pushState(null, null, location.href);
window.onpopstate = function () {
    history.go(1);
    console.log("back");
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called twice because `onpopstate` is triggered once when the Back button is clicked in the browser. Then you call `history.go(1)` again which moves the history forward and hence calls `popstate` one more time.

Technically that also calls `history.go(1)` again, which would create an infinite loop, but as you're at the top of the history stack, nothing happens.

Note that if you're expecting this to be a reliable way of disabling the back button, it's not. I can easily right click the back button and go to any item in the history.

There is no reliable way to disable the back button - and this is by design.

Comment: I don't need to disable at all the back button, i need to change his function like when  i click it will do something else and don't redirect me to the previous page.

Comment: That's disabling the back button.